# Accidentally deleted row from table with primary key

Tags: mysql

If you "accidentally" (Be gentle, it's been a tough morning) delete a row from a table that has a primary key, is it possible to re-insert the record with it's previous key, even if the table auto increments the primary key?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Did you try?

Comment: One of my users made an edge case mistake which I've now fixed through validation. But it's in a production environment so I didn't want to try to insert until I knew with certainty that I would be able to set the pk for that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AUTO_INCREMENT` feature will assign a value if one is not provided in the `INSERT` or `REPLACE` statement. Otherwise, if you supply a value and it does not conflict with the existing keys, it will be accepted as-is.

Answer (score 2):

TSQL I've got a really weird environment - very restricted in some ways and sadly open in others. Won't allow insert of already used PK values, had to recreate the whole table...

```
/****
create protoTable w/ same structure as your mainTable that has the data you are trying to fix in this example the fieldname of the primary key is FldPK
assumption here is that your primary key is getting auto incremented
get a list of the fields in the mainTable that are NOT NULL.
in this example those fields are <not null fields>
get a list of all fields in the mainTable
in this example <all fields>, rather than spell out the fields. DO NOT INCLUDE the primary key field name
***/
declare @x int, @y int, @iLast int
select @iLast = (select MAX( FldPK ) from mainTable)
set @x = 1
while @x <= @iLast
begin
  select @y = (select COUNT(*) from mainTable where FldPK = @x)
  if @y = 1
    begin
      insert into protoTable(<all fields>)
        select <all fields> from mainTable where FldPK = @x
    end
  else
    begin
      insert into protoTable (<not null fields> )values('N','xyz'+convert(varchar,@x)) /*or whatever values are valid to fulfill not null*/
      /* this is where you keep one or more of the missing rows to update later with the lost data */
      if @x <> 126
        begin
          delete protoTable where FldPK = @x
        end
    end
  set @x=@x+1
end
```

Then rename the mainTable to backup and rename protoTable to mainTable

hth